# Update model value doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, templates, vuejs3, emit, vue-options-api

I'm using v-model to connect two components.

I'm trying to pass value to father components and first gave me undefined. I changed code like second and that worked.
My question is this: why does not worked in script > methods section.But worked in html section

My UI-component code is like this :

```
<template> 
  <input
    :value="modelValue"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
  />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Input",
  props: {
    modelValue: [String, Number],
  },
   methods: {
     uptadeInput(e) {
       this.$emit("uptade:modelValue", e.target.value);
     },
   },
};
</script>
<style></style>
```

That did not work and changed code like this :

```
<template>
  <input
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
  />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Input",
  props: {
    modelValue: [String, Number],
  },
};
</script>
```

That worked in html section.

Comment: Please do not use `\`` backticks as apostrophes since they have a meaning in Stackoverflow's markdown

Comment: you don't call `uptadeInput` in your first piece, so the model isnt updated

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you never call the 'uptadeInput' method.
To call the method from the input event:

```html
<input
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="uptadeInput"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
/>
```

In the second example you calling `$emit` from the `input` event.